# Error:Error: Fragments should be static such that they can be re-instantiated by the system, and anonymous classes are not static [ValidFragment]

Tags: android

Пытаюсь зарелизить приложение выдает ошибку, а так все работает четко. Как мне кажется ругается DatePickerFragment. Что это? Как пофиксить?

Тут может быть проблема?

```
//Календарь возвращает текущее время
    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    //Добавим к времени час если указана только дата (без времени), для срабатывания.
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + 1 );


    //Слушатель для выбора Даты
    etDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Проверка на длину текста в поле
            if (etDate.length() == 0) {
                etDate.setText(" ");
            }
            DialogFragment datePickerFragment = new DatePickerFragment() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                    etDate.setText(Utils.getDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis()));
                }
                //При нажатии "Отмена" текст не устанавливался
                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    etDate.setText(null);
                }
            };
            datePickerFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "DatePickerFragment");
        }
    });
    //Слушатель для выбора Времени
    etTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (etTime.length() == 0){
                etTime.setText(" ");
            }
            DialogFragment timePickerFragment = new TimePickerFragment() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                    etTime.setText(Utils.getTime(calendar.getTimeInMillis()));
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    etTime.setText(null);
                }
            };
            timePickerFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "TimePickerFragment ");
        }
    });

    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_add, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            task.setTitle(etTitle.getText().toString());
            task.setStatus(ModelTask.STATUS_CURRENT);
            if (etDate.length() != 0 || etTime.length() != 0 ){
                task.setDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());

                AlarmHelper alarmHelper = AlarmHelper.getInstance();
                alarmHelper.setAlarm(task);
            }
            task.setStatus(ModelTask.STATUS_CURRENT);
            addingTaskListener.onTaskAdded(task);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            addingTaskListener.onTaskAddingCancel();
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
```

Класс DatePickerFragment

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
    implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {


@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

}
```

Фрагмент вынесен отдельно...

Сделал как сказали проверка показала на  этот кусок кода, ниже укажу строчку

```
    @Override
public void addTask(ModelTask newTask, boolean saveToDB) {
    int position = -1;
    ModelSeparator separator = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getItemCount(); i++) {
        if (adapter.getItem(i).isTask()) {
            ModelTask task = (ModelTask) adapter.getItem(i);
            if (newTask.getDate() < task.getDate()) {
                position = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (newTask.getDate() != 0) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(newTask.getDate());
        if (calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) < Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)) {
            newTask.setDateStatus(ModelSeparator.TYPE_OVERDUE);
            if (!adapter.containsSeparatorOverdue) {
                adapter.containsSeparatorOverdue = true;
                separator = new ModelSeparator(ModelSeparator.TYPE_OVERDUE);
            }
        } else if (calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) > Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)) {
            newTask.setDateStatus(ModelSeparator.TYPE_FUTURE);
            if (!adapter.containsSeparatorFuture) {
                adapter.containsSeparatorFuture = true;
                separator = new ModelSeparator(ModelSeparator.TYPE_FUTURE);
            }
        } else if (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) < Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) &&
                calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) == Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)) {
            newTask.setDateStatus(ModelSeparator.TYPE_OVERDUE);
            if (!adapter.containsSeparatorOverdue) {
                adapter.containsSeparatorOverdue = true;
                separator = new ModelSeparator(ModelSeparator.TYPE_OVERDUE);
            }
        } else if (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) == Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) &&
                calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) == Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)) {
            newTask.setDateStatus(ModelSeparator.TYPE_TODAY);
            if (!adapter.containsSeparatorToday) {
                adapter.containsSeparatorToday = true;
                separator = new ModelSeparator(ModelSeparator.TYPE_TODAY);
            }
        } else if (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) == Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) + 1 && // <-- Ругается на эту строку на кусок после "==" - Сообщение такое - "Must be one of: Calendar.SUNDAY, Calendar.MONDAY, Calendar.TUESDAY, Calendar.WEDNESDAY, Calendar.THURSDAY, Calendar.FRIDAY, Calendar.SATURDAY less... (Ctrl+F1)"
                calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) == Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)) {
            newTask.setDateStatus(ModelSeparator.TYPE_TOMORROW);
            if (!adapter.containsSeparatorTomorrow) {
                adapter.containsSeparatorTomorrow = true;
                separator = new ModelSeparator(ModelSeparator.TYPE_TOMORROW);
            }
        } else if (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) > Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) + 1 &&
                calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) == Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)) {
            newTask.setDateStatus(ModelSeparator.TYPE_FUTURE);
            if (!adapter.containsSeparatorFuture) {
                adapter.containsSeparatorFuture = true;
                separator = new ModelSeparator(ModelSeparator.TYPE_FUTURE);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Где и при каких действиях возникает и отображается ошибка?

Comment: При попытки генерировать проект из "Дебаг" в "релиз"  (Андроид Студио)

Comment: Я думаю, что ошибка сия намекает на то, что где-то у вас фрагмент объявлен не в отдельном файле и не в виде врутреннего статического класса, а в виде анонимного класса. По идее, если вы вынесите этот фрагмент в отдельный файл то проблема исчезнет

Comment: Вы добавили большой кусок кода, но что-то строчки, на которую анализатор ругается, я не вижу

Comment: Я мучаюсь с этой же проблемой уже который день. @Eugene Zaychenko, вы решили проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас где-то объявлен фрагмент как анонимный или не статический вложенный класс. Так делать нехорошо, по тому что система может прибить активность вместе с фрагментом, например, при сворачивании, а потом восстановить. При восстановлении может создаться новый экземпляр фрагмента и для этого будет использоваться конструктор по умолчанию без параметров. У вложенных не статических классов все конструкторы неявно принимают в качестве параметра экземпляр класса (грубо говоря, для пояснения ситуации подойдет), поэтому все фрагменты должны объявляться как отдельные классы, или как статические вложенные классы. Т.е. вместо

```
class MyFragment extends Fragment {
```

объявленного внутри другого класса, должны быть

```
static class MyFragment extends Fragment {
```

И да, вы не сможете так просто ссылаться на экземпляр внешнего класса, его придется как-то иначе получать.

Ну и еще такого кода надо избегать:

```
new MyFragment() {
    // some methods overriding
}
```

Это и есть анонимный класс. И он неявно ссылается на класс, в котором вы его объявили.

Плюс ко всему у каждого фрагмента обязательно должен быть конструктор без параметров.

Comment: Я добавил код в котором может быть проблема, но тут вроде все правильно. Фрагмент вынесен в отдельный файл, а при нажатии создаем его новый экземпляр. Тут есть ошибка?

Comment: @EvgeniyZaychenko c DatePickerFragment вроде бы все нормально, но ошибка может возникать из-за другого фрагмента.
Попробуйте в студии Analyze->Inspect Code, в настройках InspectionProfile поставьте галочку только для Fragment not instantiatable и запустите проверку. По идее вы должны увидеть не только абстрактное сообщение об ошибке, но и конкретную строку или по крайней мере класс.

Comment: И еще не забудьте предварительно клонировать профиль Inspections и  так или иначе вернуть все обратно. Оно вам еще пригодится и будет подсвечивать всякие разные ошибки.

Comment: Сделал как написали, выдала 1 строчку, помню она ругалась на нее раньше, но я что-то нажал (выбрал один из предложенных вариантов решения) и подчеркивание исчезло, но не так все просто :)) В коде указал строку на которую ругается.

Comment: В последнем блоке кода передвиньте на центр горизонтальный бегуок прокрутки

Comment: @EvgeniyZaychenko это просто нестрашный warning, о нем стоит задуматься, т.к. там есть ошибка и оно будет не очень корректно работать, например, в воскресенье. Но сборке это не должно мешать. Релизная сборка все так же не собирается?

Comment: Да, но теперь явно подчеркивает DatePickerFragment и TimePickerFragment смс ошибки

'Fragments should be static such that they can be re-instantiated by the system, and anonymous classes are not static less... (Ctrl+F1)

Comment: From the Fragment documentation: Every fragment must have an empty constructor, so it can be instantiated when restoring its activity's state. It is strongly recommended that subclasses do not have other constructors with parameters, since these constructors will not be called when the fragment is re-instantiated; instead, arguments can be supplied by the caller with setArguments(Bundle) and later retrieved by the Fragment with getArguments().

Comment: Походу ему не нравятся то что нет конструктора без параметров у  DatePickerFragment  и TimePickerFragment

Comment: @EvgeniyZaychenko Да, именно.

Comment: Добавил в ответ про конструктор.

Comment: Класс DatePickerFragment  я выкладывал в первом посте, там конструктора вообще не касались, т.е. используется по умолчанию (код в 1 посте). Не понимаю, что еще надо.

Comment: Указал явно пустой конструктор в обоих классах, все равно не собирается релиз.

Comment: @EvgeniyZaychenko и пишет все то же самое?

Comment: @EvgeniyZaychenko вот же у вас анонимный класс создается `DialogFragment datePickerFragment = new DatePickerFragment() {`
А в ответе про анонимные классы тоже сказано. И в ошибке они вроде бы упоминаются.

Comment: DialogFragment datePickerFragment; - нужно вынести выше в корень класса?

Comment: @EvgeniyZaychenko по хорошему вам тут нужен не фрагмент, а диалог. Например DatePickerDialog. Или свой AlertDialog.
Когда вы пишете `new DatePickerFragment() { какой-то код внутри  DatePickerFragment}`, вы неявным образом создаете новый подкласс DatePickerFragment, который является вложенным не статическим классом. И у него неявно создается конструктор, который принимает в качестве параметра класс, в котором этот код вызывается.

Comment: Да, изменил на DatePickerDialog и эту строчку пропустило, но уперлось в другую... где тот же способ. Спасибо, пойду исправлять, криворукий код.

Answer (score 0):

Добавь в  `build.gradle`

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```